# How to predict residuals using ARCH model

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, residuals, garch

I have been reading about the autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity (ARCH) models and they seem amazing. I Understand that the model captures the volatile of the variance of residuals. However, is there a way to simulate and get some residual predictions. I am trying to use it for a model. I have fitted seasonality and trend to descent degree but I would like to include the residuals (I know they are random but ARCH some to offer some information to simulate them to a degree).

I am using Python and I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you looking for a python package or some theoretical background or something else? Can you clarify?

Comment: Both a theoretical approach and implementation using the ARCH library. From my understanding I can obtain a plot of the variance (let say daily variance). In additionthe python library can give the mean using the ARCHModelForecast. Do I then use this information to randomly sample from a gaussian distribution?

Comment: ARCH should give you a prediction for $\sigma_{t+1}$ then you can multiply that with samples of your error. Note that your error does not have to be Gaussian, but you are free to use Gaussian errors if you want to assume so.

Comment: I understand that it gives predictions for \sigma_{t+1}. However, what do you mean to multiply that with samples of my error? Also if I assume Gasussian, which mean should I use?